# How to use GetType on a generic type using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is it possible using reflection to get type of a generic class?  My generic class:

```
public class ItemResponse<TItem>: ItemBase where TItem: Item
{
    public bool HasMore { get; set; }
    public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
}
```

Debit class inherits from Item:

```
public class Debit: Item
{
   public string ABBREVTYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Item from ItemBase:

```
public class Item: ItemBase
{
    public string CREATEDBY { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible using Type.GetType to get ItemResponse?

Something like this (this is the part I dont know about):

```
var myType = "namespace.ItemResponse[namespace.Debit]";
var genericItemType = Type.GetType(myType);
```

Comment: Do you mean `namespace+ItemResponse\`1[namespace.Debit]`?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to manipulate the type names, not the types itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find 'ItemResponse' from GetType() or typeof();

```
var type = typeof(ItemResponse<Debit>);
Console.WriteLine(type.Name);//prints ItemResponse`1
Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);//prints MyApp.ItemResponse`1[[MyApp.Debit, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

It's in both the FullName property of the type object.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `1 in your type name. Something like this should work:

```
var myType = "Namespace.ItemResponse`1[Namespace.Debit]"
var genericItemType = Type.GetType(myType);
```